# mkfifo don't make a FIFO special file

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fifo, mkfifo

when i compile my program it does not create a fifo type file, yet i change the permission, but still nothing
I also changed files but still nothing, the code compiles without problem, however when I run then I check if the fifo file is generated, but it is not so no file is generated

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define FIFO_NAME "/tmp/my_fifo"
#define BUFFER_SIZE PIPE_BUF
#define TEN_MEG (1024 * 1024 * 10)

int main()
{
    int pipe_fd;
    int res;
    int open_mode = O_WRONLY;
    int bytes_sent = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    res = mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0777);
    if (access(FIFO_NAME, F_OK) == -1) {
        res = mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0777);
        if (res != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not create fifo %s\n", FIFO_NAME);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("Process %d opening FIFO O_WRONLY\n", getpid());
    pipe_fd = open(FIFO_NAME, open_mode);
    printf("Process %d result %d\n", getpid(), pipe_fd);

    if (pipe_fd != -1) {
        while(bytes_sent < TEN_MEG) {
            res = write(pipe_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (res == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Write error on pipe\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            bytes_sent += res;
        }
        (void)close(pipe_fd); 
    }
    else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);        
    }

    printf("Process %d finished\n", getpid());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

here is the code of the second entity with which the first communicates

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define FIFO_NAME "/tmp/my_fifo"
#define BUFFER_SIZE PIPE_BUF

int main()
{
    int pipe_fd;
    int res;
    int open_mode = O_RDONLY;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    int bytes_read = 0;

    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
   
    printf("Process %d opening FIFO O_RDONLY\n", getpid());
    pipe_fd = open(FIFO_NAME, open_mode);
    printf("Process %d result %d\n", getpid(), pipe_fd);

    if (pipe_fd != -1) {
        do {
            res = read(pipe_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            bytes_read += res;
        } while (res > 0);
        (void)close(pipe_fd);
    }
    else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Process %d finished, %d bytes read\n", getpid(), bytes_read);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: An obvious question - do the `mkfifo` calls actually succeed? That is, did the error msg print?

Comment: no error messages

Comment: Please show your run log including how you verify the result.

Comment: $  gcc -Wall fifo3.c -o fifo3                                                                      
$ ./fifo3                                                                                          
Process 32106 opening FIFO O_WRONLY                                                                
hey

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64849454/edit) the question to add the info rather than putting them into comments.

Comment: I ran the program and send a message but there is no fifo file to create
  I don't know if I can send a picture of my file

Comment: You have two calls to `mkfifo`, but you're only checking to see if the second one fails. Why? Hint: What happens if there's already a regular file with the same name as the FIFO you want to make?

Comment: Why would you send a picture of the file if you are saying no file was created? Please describe more clearly how you are determining that the `mkfifo` failed. What exactly did you run and observe?

Comment: the first call I have it because the file was not created

Comment: I have run execute ./fifo 3 which the executable of my program

Comment: no I don't have a standard file with the same name as fifo, however my program is called fifo3. I don't think that is the name because I have executed other code with other diffferents but still no files to create

Comment: @kaylum  like i said when i compile the code there is no error.

when i run the code, there is no problem, but the FIFO file in which the information is supposed to be passed is not created

Comment: @Joseph I do not check if the second fails it is a forgotten one I added that because the file not being created;

I just wanted to see if the file was going to be created or of the condition

Comment: And like I said - show how you are checking for the file. Show the exact command and exact output.

Comment: In the terminal, I enter the command cd tmp then ls -l
or I will look directly in the tmp file

Comment: I think you want `cd /tmp`.  You might have a subdirectory of the current directory named `tmp`, but that's not where the fifo is being created.

Comment: @Nate so where was it created ?

Comment: @essayator: In `/tmp`, i.e. the directory called `tmp` which is a subdirectory of the root directory `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is blocking.  The open will block if no process is reading.
For example, you might read from the fifo using:

```
cat /tmp/my_fifo
```

Here is a modified version of your code, to demonstrate:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define FIFO_NAME "/tmp/my_fifo"
#define BUFFER_SIZE PIPE_BUF
#define TEN_MEG (1024 * 1024 * 10)
int main()
{
    int pipe_fd;
    int res;
    int open_mode = O_WRONLY;
    int bytes_sent = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    res = mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666);
    if (access(FIFO_NAME, F_OK) == -1) {
        res = mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666);
        if (res != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not create fifo %s\n", FIFO_NAME);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("Process %d opening FIFO O_WRONLY\n", getpid());

    pipe_fd = -1;
    while(pipe_fd == -1) {
      printf("Sleeping in loop \n");
      sleep(1);

      //Either of these versions work, but one will block, while the
      //other will allow the loop to run
//    pipe_fd = open(FIFO_NAME, open_mode ); // blocking version
    pipe_fd = open(FIFO_NAME, open_mode | O_NONBLOCK); // non-blocking
    }
    printf("Process %d result %d\n", getpid(), pipe_fd);

    char greeting[] = "Hi there\n";
    write(pipe_fd, greeting, strlen(greeting));


    printf("Process %d finished\n", getpid());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

You can use the open() line with O_NONBLOCK  or the one without.  In either case the process will wait until someone reads from the fifo.

Comment: Yes but it's a communication between two entities suddenly the other entity is supposed to read rather than add content directly, it should be entered in the terminal